# How can I add methods to an entity (Extending)

Tags: java, jpa

Suppose I have an entity like this

```
package entity;

[imports]

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")

public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Short id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name= "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

public Category() {
}

public Category(Short id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Category(Short id, Date date) {
    this.id = id;
    this.date= date;
}

public Short getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Short id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date= date;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}
```

}

I need to add some methods to this entity. eg the above example has `Date` but what I need is `Calendar`. So I tried extending the Category by

```
public class CategoryExt extends Category{
private Calendar calendar;

public Calendar getCalendar() {
    Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.setTime(this.getDate());
    return calendar;
}
```

}

But when I try to cast or specify that the fetched items should be of collection
`Collection<CategoryExt>` I get an error that Category cannot be converted to CategoryExt which I am guessing has something to do with downcasting error.
How do I properly add methods by extending? I don't want to alter the entity itself because I don't want to keep on modifying it every time I autogenerate it with the IDE.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to have class hierarchy (extending) or you just think that it is not possible to add business methods to the entity?

Comment: you have an unused class-field in `CategoryExt`. ;D

Comment: @LeosLiterak yes I want to extend, I know it's possible to add business methods to the entity but I prefer not to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the Inheritance:

```
public class Category extends CategoryBase implements Serializable {...}
```

With a abstract class

```
public abstract class CategoryBase {
  public abstract long getDate();  // long or whatever

  public Calendar getCalendar() {
    Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.setTime(getDate());
    return calendar;
  }
}
```

But know: To extend a Javabean for a non-Javabean-method is ugly.

Comment: Your solution worked best for me. I have thought and re-thought and this is the only way I can easily accomplish what I need. Could you please explain further what problems I might encounter if I use this approach.

Comment: You might become problems with frameworks. With collegues and patterns.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you shouldn't extend `Category` entity at all.
Just create some helper class with function which returns `Calendar` if you pass `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

See, if you get an entity i.e.:

```
session.get(Category.class,1);
```

The result is not a Category, its already a superclass of Category (or proxy, sometimes adapter).

What you try to do is very ugly because Category is a JavaBean, a java-bean does not support such business-logic like extra-methods or complex calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following tutorial, it will help you to build your inheritance. Basicly you need to introduce discriminator property in table and JPA will then know which entity is persisted in this row. On the other hand you cannot "cast" one entity to another. This will not work.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html